# Sorting voice commands by creation / modification date in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to sort voice commands by creation / modification date in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this that I know of. Modification dates are not saved in the command file of Dragon.

If you need a handy tool for managing your commands, you might want to look into SayWhatPro (http://www.speechutilities.com/SayWhatPro/ - not affiliated).